# SQL Syntax: create table with key tuple

Tags: mysql, sql

In the table creation statement

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `test` ( 
  `field1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `field1` (`field1`),
  KEY `field2` (`field2`, `field1`)
);
```

what do the `KEY` definitions mean? I know what primary keys are, but I don't know what the tuple definition (especially of `field2`) behind the keys means.

In my setup, I'm using MySQL.

Comment: This is essentially a syntax for building indexes when you create the table.

Comment: To cite the docs: _KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX_